# MYSQL PHP Query Taking Too Long

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple question or problem that I can't get for the life of me. I have a MYSQL query in PHP, but it takes forever to load seeming the database it is accessing holds many rows 1 thousand plus more. With the current script below it loads in around 25 seconds and that's with 6,000 rows.

```
$SQLGetUsers = $odb -> query("SELECT m.id,m.userid,m.btc,m.unpaidbtc,m.addedbtc,m.ltc,m.unpaidltc,m.addedltc,m.totalbtcmined,m.totalltcmined,u.totalbtcreward,u.totalltcreward, SUM(r.totalbtcdeposited) AS value_sum1, SUM(r.totalltcdeposited) AS value_sum2 
  FROM miner m 
  LEFT JOIN users u ON m.userid = u.ID
  LEFT JOIN referrals r ON m.userid = r.refid ");

while ($getInfo = $SQLGetUsers -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
  $ID = $getInfo['id'];
  $userid = $getInfo['userid'];
  $totalbtc = $getInfo['btc'];
  $totalunpaidbtc = $getInfo['unpaidbtc'];
  $addedbtc = $getInfo['addedbtc'];
  $totalltc = $getInfo['ltc'];
  $totalunpaidltc = $getInfo['unpaidltc'];
  $addedltc = $getInfo['addedltc'];
  $totalbtcmined = $getInfo['totalbtcmined'];
  $totalltcmined = $getInfo['totalltcmined'];

  ///////////////////////////////////////////////

    $newBTCbalance = ($totalbtc);

    $btctoadd = number_format($newBTCbalance / 45 / 24 / 60 / 60 * 3, 10);
    $newbtcvalue = $totalunpaidbtc + $btctoadd;
    $odb->exec("UPDATE miner SET addedbtc = '$btctoadd', unpaidbtc = '$newbtcvalue' WHERE `id` = '$ID'");

    $newLTCbalance = ($totalltc);

    $ltctoadd = number_format($newLTCbalance / 45 / 24 / 60 / 60 * 3, 10);
    $newltcvalue = $totalunpaidltc + $ltctoadd;
    $odb->exec("UPDATE miner SET addedltc = '$ltctoadd', unpaidltc = '$newltcvalue' WHERE `id` = '$ID'");

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  $minedbtc = $btctoadd + $totalbtcmined;
  $minedltc = $ltctoadd + $totalltcmined;
  $odb->exec("UPDATE miner SET totalbtcmined = '$minedbtc', totalltcmined = '$minedltc' WHERE `id` = '$ID'");
}
```

I am not sure what I can do to speed the query up so it runs in less then 1 second, is that even possible? Well anyways can anyone help make this run quicker?

Comment: A couple of things here. Firstly, you're updating the same miner 3 times. Why not do just 1 update at a time. Secondly, in MySQL, run your queries with `EXPLAIN` prepended to the query. I.e.: `EXPLAIN SELECT m.id, ...` and add that to your question as there might be something you can improve on there (index wise)

Comment: Just gonna throw this out there that you should be using prepared statements to avoid SQL injection. Especially considering you are making something associated with currency so you are a bigger target.

Comment: You should help us help you. Remove all code we don't need. Then please do some debugging: is the query slow (run it in a client)? if so we only need to look at sql. Add explain and database scheme. Is the query ok but the building of the website slow? etc etc. Don't randomly put all code here, but a small example (for instance, try to remove all thos additions. if it doesn't really matter, then we don't really need to see those, do we?)

Comment: @Tom Ok I see that now, will add them into 1 query.

Comment: @Nanne The issue is the SQL and the website building is fine as there is only PHP on the page.

Comment: then you might be better of asking a question about the sql. Show what sql is slow and what the database scheme is. Show is an explain of the slow SQL next to the scheme as well.

Comment: Make sure you have indexes on referrals.refid and users.ID.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to overcome this issue is using LIMIT clause.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/limit-optimization.html

Let say you have a query to list all the blog post and you have over 10k posts the query would take ages to execute. Generally people use LIMIT clause to get certain amount of data from MySQL database and create a pagination.

## EXAMPLE

```
$query = $query->query("SELECT * FROM data LIMIT 10"); // Only get 10 data from query

$query = $query->query("SELECT * FROM data LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10"); // The data from index 9 will be retrived make the OFFSET value dynamic
```

Comment: I've known about it, but how would the LIMIT help if the data it is looking for is further then 10 rows in? Wouldn't it never get anything done seeming it can't go through all 6,000 rows?

Comment: Use OFFSET with limit.

Comment: What type of data is retrieved? I mean it is a login data/Blog post/comment? Yes @Meezaan-ud-Din idea is good you can create a dynamic OFFSET value.

Comment: @RajendranNadar It's data that is stored for every user on the server, it then runs through it adding an amount of money to each account depending on what the account's membership is.

Comment: @RajendranNadar I don't think a limit would work as I am trying to run the query through every row to add money to each account. Wouldn't that help just if it was a login or I am looking for the data?

Comment: Rather find out if there is an index issue with the query before limiting the results.